# Allow "/" forward slash in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var patt = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9.!@#&*\-\u0080-\u052F])[a-zA-Z0-9\s.!@#&*',\-\u0080-\u052F]*$/;
console.log(patt.test("\u002f"));
```

I know that u002f is a forward slash in Unicode.  I've tried adding that to the pattern as well as "/" and haven't been able to get it to log true  yet.

Comment: If `\002f` is a forward slash, why does your pattern contain `\u052f`?

Comment: u052F is  another character we need to include.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is easy to add a forward slash, just escape it. No need using any character references or entities.

```
var patt = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9.!@#&*\-\u0080-\u052F])[\/a-zA-Z0-9\s.!@#&*',\-\u0080-\u052F]*$/;
                                                    ^
```

```js
var patt = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9.!@#&*\-\u0080-\u052F])[\/a-zA-Z0-9\s.!@#&*',\-\u0080-\u052F]*$/;
alert(patt.test("/test"));
```

Comment: Just FYI: inside a character class, in some JS implementations, you may even use `/` unescaped, e.g. `/[\d/]+/g` will match `12/24`. However, it is not a good idea since it is not portable (in Ruby, it will cause a `unterminated regexp` exception, in PHP, you may get a `Unknown modifier` error if you use `/` as a delimiter). You should consider using `/` unescaped in regex implementations where no regex delimiters are used (C#, Python, Java, Go) and in constructor notations (JavaScript, Ruby).

Answer (score 11):

You can escape a `/` character, by using `\/`.

Using unicode will actually result in the **absolute same** result, as using the character itself - and therefore will not solve your problem.